# Deriving the Dirac equation & Dirac matrices

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I'm learning about how the Dirac equation came about.

In pg. 20 of  the Lectures on Quantum Field Theory [book](http://gr.xjtu.edu.cn/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=21699&folderId=2383653&name=DLFE-82650.pdf) by Ashok Das, pg.20,  the author starts with the energy momentum relation

$$p^\mu p_\mu=m^2$$
in matrix form and then defines the matrix square root of $p_\mu p^\mu $ as
$$\overline{p}=\gamma^\mu p_\mu$$
where $\overline{p}^2=p_\mu p^\mu$. It was also stated that $\gamma^\mu$ are four linearly independent matrices.

He then wrote the following relationship for the $\gamma^\mu$ matrices in eqn. 1.78:
$$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu={1\over 2}(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu).$$

How did he arrive at this relationship? In general, linearly independent matrices don't commute, so $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \neq \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu$.

I'm think this relationship holds for Dirac matrices, but the author uses this relationship to later on derive the Dirac matrices. Isn't that a circular argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you've made this conclusion from the derivations in equation 1.78 in the cited book, which proceed as follows

$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu = p^2 \mathbf{1} \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu) p_\mu p_\nu = p^2 \mathbf{1}$$

This *does not* imply that $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu)$ (which, as you've already noticed, would in turn imply $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu = \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu$, which is false).

Instead, what the author does is take the identity in the first row with indices swapped $\nu \leftrightarrow \mu$, which reads

$$\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu p_\nu p_\mu = p^2 \mathbf{1}$$

and adds it to the original identity:

$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu p_\nu p_\mu = 2p^2 \mathbf{1}$$

Now, use the fact that $p_\mu$ and $p_\nu$ commute:

$$(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu) p_\mu p_\nu = 2p^2 \mathbf{1}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu) p_\mu p_\nu = p^2 \mathbf{1}$$

Comment: Thank a lot! I'll accept this answer when I can.

Comment: @TaeNyFan Glad to be of help! Good luck on your QFT path.